# how I can skip passing optional parameter to stored procedure in Linq to SQL

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

I am using Linq to SQL with stored procedures.

I have to pass parameters to stored procedures even if they are optional (where I have set the default value for parameters in stored procedures). Is there any way that I may skip passing default parameters.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this: http://challadotnetfaq.blogspot.com/2009/05/stored-procedure-optional-parameters.html

you can if you map the sp to a method with optional parameters

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned link in marked answer is dead, I put the idea here for future readers (*of course I didn't read the mentioned article, but below way will work, I tested before posting here*)

You need to overload auto-generated method of your `SP` (*in .designer.cs class*) and cut your optional parameter(s) (as you know, By default, when you drop a stored procedure onto `DBMLclass` file, it only auto-generates the default function)

For ex. with this `SP`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_Test
    @optionalParam INT = 0
AS
    -- your logic gose here
```

In `.designer.cs` you will got something like below by default

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.FunctionAttribute(Name="dbo.sp_Test")]
public ISingleResult<sp_TestResult> sp_Test([global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(Name="optionalParam", DbType="Int")] System.Nullable<int> optionalParam)
{
    IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), optionalParam);
    return ((ISingleResult<sp_TestResult>)(result.ReturnValue));
}
```

So you need to `overload` this, here is the code:

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.FunctionAttribute(Name="dbo.sp_Test")]
public ISingleResult<sp_sp_TestResult> sp_Test()
{
    IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())));
    return ((ISingleResult<sp_sp_TestResult>)(result.ReturnValue));
}
```

**Remember**

- The `DBML designer file` will be re-generated every time you add/remove any SP or table to it, so make sure to keep your methods before you do save on it, or alternatively move all overloaded methods to a new partial class.
- If you have SPs with many optional parameters, you will have to generate overloaded methods for all possible combinations, and that can get annoying fast. Also, in this case you will have to call the SP with named parameters

Comment: The link is live again btw.

Comment: For you maybe, but for me returns 404 !

Comment: Certainly works, please double check the URL is not cropped and that you don't have an addin that might block it. If it still does not work, that might be your provider blocking it.

Comment: This was very succinct and excellent! Especially important to remember is the DBML regeneration. Always put these overloaded methods in a partial class as he mentioned in the "Remember" section.